# rails on heroku: external mysql attempts connection to amazon when other url specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mysql2

Getting the "we're sorry, but something's wrong" error, trying to configure external mysql to work with rails app...already using proximo and app has been whitelisted

```
$ heroku config: yields
DATABASE_URL: mysql2://USR:PWRD@184.172.191.156:3306/DB
```

No errors in heroku logs, if I open console and query db I see

```
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'USR'@'ec2-54-235-3-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
```

Why is the app trying to access the database at amazon and how to change this?

Comment: Hav you granted access to remote IP address in your mysqldb?

Comment: Are you able to connect from your desktop to this database? *I'm just trying to figure out where the problem is - in amazon or in heroku.

Comment: I can connect with my local setup fine - my external database is not at amazon and I am not using any amazon gems etc

Comment: Try to grant access in mysql for exact user from error message: 'USR'@'ec2-54-235-3-198.compute-1.amazonaws.com'

Comment: It's really interesting cause I faced same problem about year ago and spend a lot of time, as I remember my problem was in granting access.